# How would I make an h2 element show up after one of three buttons is clicked, then have part of the h2 element appear after the primary part shows up?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, event-listener

I am trying to get the following information to appear on the screen after one of the buttons(rock paper or scissors) is clicked: "The winner is..." I would like the text "the winner is" to show up first, followed by the three "." one at a time. How would I make this work? Here is my code:

```
 <div class="selections">
  <button class="selection" data-selection="&#128507;">&#128507;</button>
  <button class="selection" data-selection="&#128220;">&#128220;</button>
  <button class="selection" data-selection="&#9986;">&#9986;</button>
</div>
<!--
<h2 id="win">The winner is<span id="dot">...</span></h2>
-->
```

```js
function fadeIn() {
  const message = document.getElementById("win", "dot").value;
  console.log(message);
}
document.getElementsByClassName("data-selection").addEventListener("click", fadeIn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise`s:

```js
async function fadeIn() {
  const msg = document.getElementById("win");
  msg.style.display = "block";
  const dots = document.getElementById("dot");
  for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    dots.textContent += ".";
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
  }
  msg.innerHTML += " John Doe";
  console.log(message);
}
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("selection")).forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", fadeIn))
```

```css
#win {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="selections">
  <button class="selection" data-selection="&#128507;">&#128507;</button>
  <button class="selection" data-selection="&#128220;">&#128220;</button>
  <button class="selection" data-selection="&#9986;">&#9986;</button>
</div>

<h2 id="win">The winner is<span id="dot"></span></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to update the message text at regular intervals until the number of times the function runs equals the number of "."s you want.

```js
// Cache the elements
const selections = document.querySelector('.selections');
const message = document.querySelector('#win');

// Add a listener to the parent div
selections.addEventListener('click', fadeIn, false);

function fadeIn() {

  // Set the limit
  const limit = 3;

  // Set a counter
  let count = 0;

  // Create the text (the h2 is hidden at this point)
  let text = 'The winner is';

  // Add the text to the message element
  message.textContent = text;

  // Make the element visible
  message.classList.remove('hidden');

  // Until count equals the limit add one new period
  // to the message text every 1/2 second
  function loop() {
    message.textContent += '.';
    count++;
    if (count !== limit) setTimeout(loop, 500);
  }

  // Run the loop function
  loop();

}
```

```css
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<div class="selections">
  <button class="selection" data-selection="&#128507;">&#128507;</button>
  <button class="selection" data-selection="&#128220;">&#128220;</button>
  <button class="selection" data-selection="&#9986;">&#9986;</button>
</div>
<h2 id="win" class="hidden"></h2>
```

Comment: I continue to get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property "textContent" of null? What exactly does this mean? I am new to JavaScript

Comment: Can you save your HTML/JS to a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and comment with the link and I'll take a look.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/MrWil95/a29b1smj/4/ basically what I'm trying to do is get the message "The winner is. . ." to display once one of the buttons is clicked. I want to have the "..." come in one at a time, then display the players' results, the winner, and increase the score pf the winner by 1.